# Full URL links from Google AJAX API results

Tags: ajax, search

When using Google Search the results contain full URLs. Using the Google AJAX API only returns the domain name.

For example, the search "contact softkube" returns http://www.softkube.com/contact/ as the link in Google Search whereas it returns http://www.softkube.com/ ONLY as the link when using the Google AJAX API.

To see this in action, try a search in here: http://www.softkube.com/

Any ideas?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here it is !
[Show detailled URL in search results][1]
[How do I display the full URL of results?][2]

And [Google Custom Search AJAX Decoded - Using CSS Customization][3]

References :

1. ttp://www.google.com/support/forum/p/customsearch/thread?tid=6296e2738e7c787f&hl=en
2. ttp://www.google.com/support/forum/p/customsearch/thread?tid=001f08f79189721f&hl=en
3. ttp://searchtools.com/analysis/google-cse-ajax-css.html

Comment: Thank you. Works beautifully. The short answer here is add this to your CSS: #search-results-wrapper div.gs-visibleUrl.gs-visibleUrl-long { display: block; }
#search-results-wrapper div.gs-visibleUrl.gs-visibleUrl-short { display: none; } (Where #search-results-wrapper is the DIV containing your search results).

Answer (score 0):

When you click the link, it is the right url. The stuff in green is only the domain name, that's normal.

Look into the JSON response:

```
"unescapedUrl":"http://www.softkube.com/contact",
"url":"http://www.softkube.com/contact",
"visibleUrl":"www.softkube.com"
```

Comment: Yes, customizing by tapping into the JSON is possible, but it's much easier with CSS (The answer I flagged for this question). Thanks anyways. Cheers.